# Start timer countdown in iOS

Tags: ios, countdowntimer

I have a task in which I need to start timer countdown and I have days, hours, minutes and seconds but don't have any idea how to start timer with these entities. There are so many tutorials for counter but none of them were as per my requirement. For example, I'll get 20 days, 10 hours, 40 minutes and 30 seconds as ending date and starting date from server and I need to start timer from these entities. Please suggest me how to do that?

Comment: Do you need to display *time to something* in the UI, or do you simply want to do something in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go with `NSDateComponents`

```
NSDate* result;
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setMinute:0];/ use your retrieved values
    [comps setHour:0];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    result = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
```

[Use the `NSDate` into the `NSTimer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559707/ios-countdown-timer-to-specific-date)

Comment: but I need to use time components provided by the api. Please tell me how to use these values. I have updated my question with example.

Comment: whatever the time components, can't you convert into the required type . and also vice versa

Comment: I'll not use system's date as current date. Both start and end dates will be provided by server. Here is my problem otherwise I would have done this using system's current date so if you have any code for this, please share with me.

Comment: that's why, I suggest you to use NSDateComponents -(I'll not use system's date as current date. Both start and end dates will be provided by server.)